# pass the same googleMap object to many fragments

Tags: android, object, maps

i want to pass **google maps** object to multiple fragments .. for example if i have **fragment A** and **fragment B** .. i want to create a google maps on **fragment A** and when **fragment B** is open , the same maps object will be there in **fragment B** 
so , 
the user will never know that there's two fragments , he will think that it's the same page and same map , but it's two different fragments with two different layout views , but same maps and same location and zoom .. the same as **fragment A** .

Comment: why cant you send location and zoom level alone from frag a - activity - frag b then restore?

Comment: if i do this the map will load in the first time user enter fragment B

Answer (score 1):

I didnt try but as I guess, you can create a static  GoogleMap object on your first fragment (or activity that your fragments connect) then you can implement with OnMapReadyCallback to all your fragments. So you can access this static Google Maps object from all of your fragments then you can set same object on your fragments

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh No you can try

Answer (score 0):

user a shared ViewModel for all the fragments and keep GoogleMap object in ViewModel. your all fragments must have the same host activity to get the same ViewModel.